# Redirect http to https in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, https

I have a Laravel 5.2 project. Recently, I installed an SSL certificate on my website so when I type `https://example.com` in the browser it works but when I write `example.com`, it connects by HTTP.

To fix that, I added these lines to my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

After that, when I type `example.com`, the browser redirects me to `https://example.com`. That's perfect.

The problem is when I try to access the URL `http://example.com/download/get/book/volume2`, it doesn't redirect me to HTTPS. It redirects me to the index page. If I add the `s` of `https` in the URL it works fine but I need the app to redirect me from HTTP to HTTPS.

The route in routes file:

```
Route::get('download/get/book/{book}'
```

That route opens a PDF file that I have in `privates/storage` folder in the browser's tab.

EDIT:

My .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# require SSL 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Do you have other `.htaccess` files in any of those "subdirectories"? (Are they physical subdirectories?)

Comment: No, I have a 'public_html' folder, where is my .htaccess and a "privates" folder where I have all views, controllers,etc

Comment: In that case, where in your `.htaccess` file have you added these directives? Please include the contents of your `.htaccess` file to your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your HTTP to HTTPS redirect needs to go near the top of your `.htaccess` file, immediately after the `RewriteEngine` directive and, importantly, *before* the Laravel *front controller*.

As a general rule, *external redirects* should always go before *internal rewrites*.

The front controller catches *all requests* (or rather requests that don't map to a physical file or directory) and rewrites these to `index.php` (that ultimately handles the routeing). The problem is that your HTTP to HTTPS redirect occurs later and converts the now rewritten URL into an external redirect to `index.php`.

Likewise, your `# Handle Authorization Header` block should also go before the *front controller* (ideally). (It will work in its current state, in per-directory `.htaccess` files, due to the looping nature of `.htaccess` files, but if you moved these directives to the server config it would fail.)

Comment: Thanks for your aswer. I made the changes you said but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Make sure you clear your browser cache before testing. The earlier (erroneous) 301s will have been cached by the browser. (It is often preferable to test with 302s for this reason - to avoid the cache.)

Answer (score 7):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Add the above two lines just below `RewriteEngine On` in your `.htaccess` file. It will automatically redirect any traffic destined for http: to https:

Finally, your .htaccess file will look like the following

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect to https
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This solution is working for me.  # Redirect to https
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

Comment: it worked to me fine in my shared hosting server

Comment: This doesn't add anything that the existing answer does not already address. In fact, the subtle changes you've made to the HTTP to HTTPS directive are incorrect. For some reason, you've changed the 301 (permanent) redirect to an _implied_ 302 (temporary) redirect. This is fine for testing, but the redirect should be a 301 in production. You've also changed the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ from `^` to `(.*)` - why? `^` is much more efficient here. The regex `(.*)` unnecessarily traverses the entire URL-path and captures a backreference, which is not being used in the directive.